# Jquery validation triggered when text field value is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way (without editing the plugin) to swap keyup or blur for change so that validation can still be triggered when the user types/deletes something.

In my case, I have something such as datetime picker, some fields auto change its value depend on other fields. When its value change( without keyup or blur because its value is set by other field) the error message should be clean.

So, I have to trigger manually in each page or is there any other way to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't swap those behaviors but what you could do is create one function that you use for validation of that field and then bind that function to the different events so that it will always trigger the validation you need.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something like that than you have to validate that field(datetime picker)
after the date is selected, just like the below one

```
//check after your date is selected
$("yourform").validate().element( "your datetime picker field" );
```

something above would work for you